# I want to use azure media services for video recording and streaming

Tags: javascript, azure, webcam, azure-media-services, video-recording

I want to record the video by using webcam in javascript and stream this video using azure media services. I have gone through the media service document but not able to solve my issue. I don't want to upload the video directly to the azure portal. Can anyone help me to record video in javascript and stream using azure media services.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming directly from a browser would require a protocol like WebRTC for ingesting. We do not currently support WebRTC for live ingest streaming. Today we only support RTMP or Smooth Streaming (Fragmented MP4 Ingest).

For details on how to do live streaming see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/media-services/latest/live-streaming-overview

For a list of supported encoders see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/recommended-on-premises-live-encoders

Comment: Thanks @johndeu for the reply. I will give you example so that will help to understand my question better.   E.g. On my application Webcam is constantly recording the user. So I want to record every sec  by using webcam, upload it to the azure storage and later I want to view the whole video recording. How to upload streams comes from webcam to the azure storage and later play the video ?

Comment: You would need to record to mp4 file locally and upload the file later to stream as an ondemand recorded asset.  Unless you have access to code to convert to RTMP or Smooth ingest format.

Comment: @johndeu I know Azure has Azure Batch and one of their 'jobs' is ffmpeg transcoding. Wouldn't it be a solution to situations like this one? A 'raw' webrtc audio/video feed, chunked in 20MB, placed into a Blob Storage, notify Azure Batch, via EventGrid, and process that job. Then placing that resulting video into another blob and do the same for AMS, having it processing the file and creating the Stream Locator?

Comment: Possible. I have not tried it so can’t comment.  If you build it release a sample for it on github.